# Copying elements from a list "n" times, EXCEL VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Im really new on Vba, so im trying to learn some to make my job less repetitive

I have a list with this format, i have about 550 rows

```
Name        N
AAAAA       2
BBBB        5
CCCCC       7
```

i need to copy each Name n times, like this

```
AAAAA    
AAAAA    
BBBBB    
BBBBB    
BBBBB    
BBBBB    
BBBBB
```

until the last name, it should be about 1500 rows

Cant find any way to do this. Please Help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple code will do it:

```
Sub expand()

    With Worksheets("Sheet2") 'Source sheet
        Dim rng As Variant
        rng = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)).Value

        Dim oRng() As Variant
        ReDim oRng(1 To Application.Sum(Application.Index(rng, 0, 2)), 1 To 1)
    End With

    Dim i As Long
    Dim k As Long
    k = 1
    For i = 1 To UBound(rng, 1)
        Dim j As Long
        For j = 1 To rng(i, 2)
            oRng(k, 1) = rng(i, 1)
            k = k + 1
        Next j
    Next i

    With Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C1") 'Ouput range
        .Resize(UBound(oRng, 1), 1).Value = oRng
    End With



End Sub
```

Comment: It worked perfectly!!! thanks

In the case that each row (the initial ones) had some more info like this
AAAA  2   item1  item 2  theres is any way to put it this way using the same code?
each row has a diff number of items, wich is the number next to each row

AAAA    item 1

AAAA    item 2

thanks in advance

Comment: That is a new question.  try to modify the code above to meet your needs.  If you are unable ask a new question referring back to this one and show what you have tried to modify to make work.  Please mark this as correct as it answers this question.